# Ionic Framework Cache Videos

Tags: caching, video, ionic-framework

Is there a way(or a library) to cache/download videos before playing them? 
I searched a lot on web but couldn't find any answer.
For image caching, i use `https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/ionic-ion-imageCacheFactory`

Any Help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I found a solution, however it consumes ram a lot, https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/manage-files-in-android-and-ios-using-ionicframework/

Comment: Have you found a better solution for this with Ionic 2 maybe?